# -webkit-transform: translate(417px, 0px)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a problem with the web kit translate property.
When I reduce the browser window an iPhone screen appears.
In the iPhone screen I have implemented a slider functionality.
You can see two arrows; left and right arrow.
When you click the right arrow it moves to the next slider,
but in the right slider the images do not show up. It is due to the web kit property.
I don't know how to fix it.
I am providing two li tags; how to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/UL3R2/

```
 <li style="display: table-cell; width: 417px; vertical-align: top; left: 0px; -webkit-transition: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"
                        data-index="0">

<li style="display: table-cell; width: 417px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid red; left: -417px; -webkit-transition: 0ms; -webkit-transform: translate(417px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"
                        data-index="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am giving exaple of one function, as you hve written many function with same functinality,

Instead of append span, keep the span there with `style="display:none"`

with the script make it visible by changing the class or attribute.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.cubeCellSecurity').each(function() {
                    var htmlText = $(this).attr('data-text');
                    $(this).append('<div class="cubeTextStyleSecurity">' + htmlText + '<span class='divStockSecurity' style="display:none">Security</span></div>');

                    $(this).hover(

                    function() {
                        $(".cubeTextStyleSecurity").style().attr("display","");
                    });

                    //function(){ $(this).style().attr("display","none"); });
                });
            }, 600);

        });
```

An if you want me to update fiddle, Please remove the unnecessary html part from fiddle